# Upload file to websites with C#

Tags: c#, http, https, upload

I'm trying to make an auto uploader to websites with C#, I have NO idea where to start.
For instance, I'm trying to create an auto uploader for http://www.fileflyer.com/default.aspx.

The website asks the user to check the "I agree to Terms of Service" and asks him to enter an email.

I know WebClient.UploadFile can be used for uploading, but how do I supply and email and check the checkbox?

Thanks from advance,
Adam.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to build the same http request as browser does. WebClient class is too light hammer for this. The class you need is [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). This one allowes you to do much more then WebClinet.

The best way to start is to read about HttpWebRequest class. Then you will need to explore structure of request from browser. Use some tool, like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Upload some file using your browser and sniff request with Fiddler. Then you can replicate the same request with HttpWebRequest.

The hecked checkbox for example will be in POST data, like: checkboxName=on